# Why am I unable to start a new row in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I had created asection with multiple columns. Now,  I wish to start a new row, so I created a new container as well. But when I run the file, the new row is not added. Instead, another column is being made. Can anyone help me in debugging this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gaegu" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand" rel="stylesheet">

  <title> Techversity </title>
  <style type="text/css">
        * {
      box-sizing: border-box
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    /* Style the tab */
    
    .tab {
      float: left;
      background-color: #e7e7e7;
      width: 20%;
      height: 700px;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
    
    .tab button {
      display: block;
      background-color: #e7e7e7;
      color: black;
      padding: 22px 16px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      text-align: left;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    
    .tab button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    /* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
    
    .tab button.active {
      background-color: white;
      border: none;
      border-top: black solid;
      border-color: grey;
    }
    /* Style the tab content */
    
    .tabcontent {
      float: left;
      padding: 0px 12px;
      width: 80%;
      border: none;
      height: 700px;
      background-color: #e7e7e7;
    }
    
    .nav-item:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    }
    
    #community-col {
      height: 300px;
    }
    
    #mission-contact:hover {
      border-color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 800px) {
      .para-padding {
        padding-left: 120px;
        padding-right: 120px;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 800px) {
      .tabcontent {
        height: 800px;
      }
      .tab {
        height: 800px;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .tab {
        height: 300px;
        width: 100vw;
      }
      #contact-mission {
        width: 5px;
      }
      .tabcontent {
        width: 100vw;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 800px) {
      #community-mission-image {
        display: none;
      }
      #community-mission-image-2 {
        display: inline;
      }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      #hidetabs {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 1023px) {
      #design-mission-image {
        width: 100px;
      }
      @media (min-width: 1150px) {
        #design-mission-image {
          min-width: 300px;
        }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#hidetabs").click(function() {
        $(".tab").hide(300);
        $("#showtabs2").show(300);
      });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#showtabs").click(function() {
        $(".tab").show(300);
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#showtabs2").click(function() {
        $(".tab").show(300);
        $("#showtabs").hide();
        $("#showtabs2").hide();
        $("#hidetabs").show();
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body class="sidebar-collapse">

  <div class="tab" id="test">
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
      <h2><i id="showtabs" class="fa fa-diamond" style="display: none;"></i><i id="hidetabs" class="fa fa-gear"></i></h2>
    </center>
    <center>
      <p style="font-family: 'Gaegu', cursive;"></p>
    </center>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen" style="font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;">Design</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')" style="font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;">Community</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')" style="font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;">Development</button>
  </div>
  <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <br>
    <br>
    <section id="services">
      <header class="section-header wow fadeInUp">

        <h1><i id="showtabs2" class="fa fa-diamond" style="display: none;"></i>
          <center>
            <p style="font-family: 'Gaegu', cursive;">f8guo</p>
          </center>
        </h1>

      </header>
      <br>
    </section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <center>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li class="nav-item" style="width: 30%">
                <a href="" class="active nav-link" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#tabone">bjkjk</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" style="width: 30%">
                <a class="nav-link" href="" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#tabtwo">fyfo</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </center>
          <div class="tab-content mt-2">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tabone" role="tabpanel">
              <p class="development-tab-content">
                <center>
                  <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
                  </h3>
                </center>
              </p>
              <p style="font-size: 20px;font-family: arial;">ri guibypyionoytfrxrexxe6r7ct78yunuuinbyvftrcreerzqxwtceytibyouiuonuununiuiyvrrcrctubtybuoyoboy8byuytvvttv
                <br>
              </p>
              <br>
              <br>

              <br>
              <center><a href="#" id="contact-mission" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="font-size: 22px;width: 300px;outline-width: 50px;height: 50px">Contact</a></center>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabtwo" role="tabpanel">
              <center>
                <h3>

                  <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
                </h3>
              </center>
              <p style="font-size: 20px;font-family: arial;">hdsyhfuihiucxhiviuszhpuoidgashoihofdiihuaugeffuhfioiohiohiohgfsoufgufguffgufgosfuoisfousfdhofshosgfhheefhhefhevr uereru0eue0e90ru r</p>

              <br>
              <br>

              <br>
              <center><a href="#" id="contact-mission" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="font-size: 22px;width: 300px;outline-width: 50px;height: 50px;font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;">Contact</a></center>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <center>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br><img src="images/webdesign.svg" id="design-mission-image" style="object-fit: scale-down;width: 190px;padding-top: 35px;overflow: hidden;">
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <br>
      <br>
      <section id="services">
        <header class="section-header wow fadeInUp">
          <center>
            <h1>MISSION</h1>
          </center>
        </header>
        <br>
      </section>
      <div class="row" id="community-row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="community-col">
          <h3>
            <center>
              <p>gsdgrr</p>
            </center>
          </h3>
          <p style="font-size: 20px;font-family: arial;margin-left: 30px;margin-right: 30px;" class="para-padding">I j[pjigihdfhighihofojs0daidsa0isda0af0dihfihsiha0finvfzfkob
            <br>
            <br>hifapifhdsodspofhIfdhihidfhhfidhfdvkjkjugofbovxhbuvobbvbouobupfvbpbpfvbibfiubiuvfvdhohovnighivingr g vrnun90ecun09enuxdhinxhfchfhinncifnicfnicf
          </p>

          <br>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <br>
      <br>
      <section id="services">
        <header class="section-header wow fadeInUp">
          <center>
            <h1>MISSION</h1>
          </center>
        </header>
        <br>
      </section>
      <div class="row" id="community-row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="community-col">
          <h3>
            <center>
              <p>Development</p>
            </center>
          </h3>
          <br>
          <p style="font-size: 20px;font-family: arial;margin-left: 30px;margin-right: 30px;" class="para-padding">ucfiuiyivhvjhcdtyfuuguilo;gggggggohkvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvhllllllllvlihhhhhhhhhhhhhh
            <br>
            <br> tkuffyuooot87cghkcgkcggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
          </p>

          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
  </script>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-10">.col-xs-6 .col-md-10</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">.col-xs-6 .col-md-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I make the data appear in a new row below the previous one? Any help will be apreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a weird error at line 154, column 5. There are two opening script tags. You should check out the bootstrap syntax as well. You shall not place a "row" without a "container"  of "fluid-container" as parent. That's why it's not working. And you shouldn't use several jquery versions in one webpage. Aaaaand never do anything before the HTML doctype tag!

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Both your question and code are pretty unclear.

Comment: I want the row at the bottom to appear below the previous row, not on the right side of the page.

Comment: It's still completely unclear to me. You want the buttons (Design, Community, Development) on top of the page, and the content below that?

Comment: "<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-10">.col-xs-6 .col-md-10</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">.col-xs-6 .col-md-2</div>
    </div>"      I want the output of this code to come below the previous div tag. Right now, it is coming at the right side of the page(you have to scroll to look at it), but I want this row to come at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies in mixing up different Bootstrap versions. Change the links to Bootstrap 4 in your `<head>` to Bootstrap 3 and your last row appears below, instead of to the right:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also, you have a link to both Bootstrap.js versions 3.3.7 and 4.0.0 in your head, so one of them should be removed anyway.

Besides that, your last two media queries are missing a closing bracket:

```
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
    #design-mission-image {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1150px) {
    #design-mission-image {
        min-width: 300px;
    }
}
```

And there are a lot of things going on in your code that you might want to clean up, like inline styling, empty tags and `<br>`s. Break down your code to the bare minimals, and it will be a lot easier to find any problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem. But the page is still letting the user scroll to the right even if no content is there? Is there any specific reason for that? Or random code problem which I can debug myself?

Comment: Also, if I change bootstrap version to 3, the other part of my real project does not work properly. Is not there any way I can make a new row in version 4?

Comment: Like I said, break down your code to the bare minimum and start from there (no extra CSS other than Bootstrap, no added fonts etc). Then start adding everything piece by piece (Javascript etc)